# User-rate limit exceeded 429 on specific domain

Tags: gmail-api

We are getting this error on the one domain we are accessing, with Java:

```
429 unknown
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2015-05-21T16:36:01.691Z",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2015-05-21T16:36:01.691Z"
}
```

We are pretty sure that we are not exceeding the User-rate limit (250 quotas) for that system. We are only doing read requests, which should count about 5 quotas each. We would expect a maximum quota usage from 150 quotas per second with what we do.
We are using an oauth2 service account to access user mailboxes.

If it occurs we are waiting for the "Retry after" date. But we are immediately getting the "User-rate limit exceeded" right after that date. 
This domain is in argentinia. While when we run the code against another domain in the US, we are NEVER getting this error.

Comment: For rate limit errors and 429(concurrent requests) errors, implement exponential back off. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors on how to implement this.

Comment: Why would an exponential back off help ??? We are pausing until the "Retry after" date from the error message. I would think that this is the best that can be done.

Comment: The documentation says leaky bucket algorithm but that's not what I've experienced. It's unpredictable so I've just had to accept that the errors can happen anywhere, anytime.  The only way I can make sense of it is that, as the limit is per-user, then the user must be using it at the same time. eg: they have an email client open and it is buzzing away somewhere chewing up quota.